# How virtual dom updates without a key

Tags: reactjs

So from my understanding the virtual DOM works in two ways for updating the elements. The below details are my findings from different articles and videos. Correct me if I am wrong.

1. if the parent element has been changed then it will remove the entire element even if child is there and update with the new parent element

   ```
   <div>
       <span>hello</span>
   </div>

   <span>
       <span>hello react</span>
   </span>
   ```
2. the other way is finding the key and updating it. Assume that inside an ul, I am rendering 6 elements as li. Now when i click on a button I am updating the last li.

So while rendering I am not passing the key, so it will show warning to pass key for React. But without passing the key also it will update.

How is it working, is it deleting the entire ul and li and recreating it?

Answer (score 0):

While reading the react js docs. The answer was mentioned .

***If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.***

React JS [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)